# Calling class methods with map

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a few instances of a class called Particle in a list called `self.plane' that i want to update simultaneously.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from timeit import default_timer as current_time

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, X_position, Y_position, X_velocity=0 ,Y_velocity=0, mass=600):
        self.mass = mass
        self.velocity = {'x':X_velocity,'y':Y_velocity}
        self.position = {'x':X_position,'y':Y_position}
        self.time_of_last_update = {'x':current_time(),'y':current_time()}

    def update(self):
        for axis in self.position:
            # Calculate time since update was last run
            elapsed_time = current_time() - self.time_of_last_update[axis]
            # Calculate acceleration
            # acceleration = force[axis] / self.mass
            acceleration = -1
            # Calculate velocity
            self.velocity[axis] = self.velocity[axis] + ( acceleration * elapsed_time )
            # Change position if needed
            if (elapsed_time >= 1 / abs( self.velocity[axis] )):
                # Calculate new postion
                self.position[axis] = self.position[axis] + int( elapsed_time * self.velocity[axis] )
                print(self.position)
                # Reset the timer
                self.time_of_last_update[axis] = current_time()
```

The map function seemed like the simplest way to go about this.

I thought that I could make `Particle.update()` receive its `self` argument as `self.plane` was iterated over.

```
workers = Pool(processes=4)
workers.map(Particle.update(), self.plane)
```

However when i run this, I get `TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: That's because you need to create an instance of the object particle = Particle(X_position=x_pos, Y_position=y_vel, X_velocity=x_vel ,Y_velocity=0, mass=600) with your values, and then, once you have an instance particle, you can call particle.update()